# What are the most mature platforms as of today?

Tags: architecture

What are the advanced and mature software platforms that can be used to create commercial software?
And what types of apps are they suited at creating?

We all know the basics:

- .NET makes quick work of Windows apps
- Flash or Silverlight for internet experiences
- MS Office addons for workflow integrated apps
- ASP, Python, ROR or PHP for web apps

What others can you actually consider for a real-world app?

Comment: thousands of users doing what, when & how often?

Comment: We use JEE not J2EE now, and JEE is only a platform:)

Comment: I'm hoping to hear of newer languages like Processing or functional programming or things I have no idea about.

Comment: newer doesn't often fit with advanced and mature until at least SP3.  F# is looking pretty awesome though.

Comment: Fortran on a PDP-11, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one's I would add to your list are:

- C++
- Objective C
- Java
- Microsoft SQL

And although not necessarily mature, but definitely advanced I would also add:

- XNA

You could probably lump that in the .NET stack, but that's a big stack.

In terms of Software Platforms I would also add:

- SharePoint

It's come a long way and is an excellent platform for workflow and web apps.

Answer (score 6):

IBM System/360: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360 (now IBM System z: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZSeries)

Comment: Meets all the requirements of "most mature"!

Comment: With Cobol, DB2, and CICS as the software platform.

Comment: Correct and better than *my* snark. But snark is usually better in the comments.